# DataTable with Fixed Column in Chrome browser it's showing space between Header and Body

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, datatable

When load datatable grid dynamically with fixed column and/or lazy loading

it's show space between Header and Body

in this space there's tr with height:0px but for some reason it's not take as height 0px 
[image]

I have try to inspect in chrome and try to change height 0px but no change

> Note: This issue only face in Chrome but in Firefox looks everything
>   fine. :/

*I can't share a code because of company policy SORRY*

Comment: should i down grate version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also facing this issue last few weeks, I found some code to fix temporary using CSS 
try to use below code

```
    /* ---- Temp Override css for resolve DataTable header spacing  ----*/
        .DTFC_ScrollWrapper .dataTables_scrollBody thead tr,.DTFC_ScrollWrapper .dataTables_scrollBody thead tr th {
    height: 0px !important;
}
        /* ------------------------------ */
```

Comment: what do mean by temporary?

Comment: As u mention above it's already have height 0px; i have reset height through the external CSS and it's works for me. i thought it's browser issue because this issue you cannot see in Mozilla Firefox browser, so,google crome developer team fix this issue after you can remove the temporary code.